# Adding event-changed item to a list

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie in C# and specially (of course!) events...

In my code, we get an element T from an event and want to add it to a list (List).

Since T is signed as "OnPropertyChanging", it changes everywhere in my code, thus all the member on List are the same. So what should I implement to save all the past values of T in  List?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT (trying to explain it better):

I have an application that receives data via DDE which I use to perform real-time calculations. Until now, no problem. My problems begin when I have to use previous data, because I haven't been able to save them in a list.

I create a list in my first data reading and add the value to it:

```
ticks = new List<Tick> { tick };   // where tick comes via DDE
```

After the second reding, I want to use the last value of the list and compare it to the newest:

```
Tick prevTick = ticks.Last();
Tick currTick = tick;              // this tick is different from the former
```

However I verify that prevTick is equal to currTick. Apparently, "PropertyChange" changes tick in all instances of the program, modifying the content of ticks before I have the chance to pass it to prevTick.

Comment: sorry are you saying you want to save current state before it is reversed. its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear. Yes. I want save past values of T before it's changed (reversed). The problem is that function A changes it before I can save it in function B where I manage the List<T>. I'd like to save the value of the previous interation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Tick` is a class, `prevTick` and `currTick` are most likely the same instance, and the underlying code providing the `Tick` instance is just updating the values stored by this instance.  This would explain your thought that `PropertyChange` changes all tick instances - it is actually only one instance

I would create my own class with a property for each piece of the data that `Tick` contains, and populate a new instance of this class for your history list.  If you just need a number from each `Tick`, then you could just have a `List<int>` to store your history.